# jquery tweets not loading

Tags: jquery, twitter

I had previously come across this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdtareque/YJfGp/) that is used to load the tweets into a html page using jquery. I am using exactly the same code.

Code for reference:

```
 $('#tweets').tweets({
           tweets:4,
           username: "twitter-username-here"
  });​
```

The fiddle is working perfectly. But when I am trying to integrate it into my site, I am not able to see any tweets getting load, nor do I see any js error.

Jquery file is getting load properly, other functionality are working fine,just the tweets are not getting loaded.

#### EDIT

I had copy pasted the above code in the file using a text-editor, when I opened the file in vim there was a garbage character '<200b>' in it. I guess, it came from copy-pasting the code from jsFiddle.
So, now I am getting the below error which is visible in browser console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'tweets'
```

Let me know, how to resolve this?

Any idea about this? What is the problem here? Have anyone come across similar situation before?

Comment: Have you put your code within document ready handler?

Comment: oh yes..it's in `document.ready`.

Comment: Do you have any issues accessing the JSON API used by tweets: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?callback=?&screen_name=<twitter-username-here>. Only thing I would say about the plugin is that it doesn't have much error handling built into it - would need to change its `getJSON` call to an `ajax` call with function to handle errors generated.

Comment: I am not facing any issues accessing the given link. Please can you tell me how to change the call from `ajax` to `getJSON` in the plugin?